# Restrictions on types sent to a function

Tags: c++, templates

I don't understand what restrictions apply to types that are passed to the function.

```
template <class T>
T sum( const T &a, const T &b) {
    return a+b; 
}
```

Comment: In your posted example, the only restrictions *I* see are that `operator+` must be available for the types passed in and that a `T` must be copy constructible from the result of that operator.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Does a `T` even have to be copy constructible? Move-constructible would also work, right? [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/7bY7xMTqd)

Comment: @NathanPierson Yes, I think you are probably right. That would probably do.

Comment: Note: There are no explicit restrictions here. The first sign of failure will be a sometimes-inscrutable wall of compiler diagnostics. C++ keeps adding new ways to vet template arguments and provide more reasonable error messages, but none have been used here.

Comment: One thing at may or may not be seen as a restriction is the fact that both parameter types need to match for automatic deduction to work: `sum(1.0, 1)` will fail to deduce `T`, since both `double` and `int` are candidates. Another restriction is that the function cannot be used in a constexpr context.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the types need to have the `+` operator defined either implicitly or overridden (eg: an `int` type or overridden for a class/struct/etc). As long as the `+` operation can be applied to the parameters, there are no restrictions.

The return type `T` will also need a constructor that accepts the result of the `+` operation